# asp: OnTreeNodeCheckedChange not firing

Tags: asp.net

I have a tree-view control on a form that is not firing when the checkbox is checked. Does anyone know a work-around for this? Thanks

```
                   <asp:TreeView ID="tv_WLG" runat="server" OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="tv_WLG_TreeNodeCheckChanged"   ShowCheckBoxes="All">
                    </asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate a `Postback` in order for your server event to fire. Add a button and press it after changing the check state of the checkboxes. Checking or unchecking the checkboxes **does not** initiate a `Postback`!

```
<asp:Button id="Submit"
        Text="Select Items"
        runat="server"/>
```

Comment: It is a top level node that automatically selects all of the nodes underneath it. So in this case, a button would be overkill on the UI.

Comment: @jpavlov Well still this is a server side event and you need to initiate a postback, otherwise your event handler has nothing to fire on.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to fire an onclick from the treeview control. Inside the onclick on the treeview, I set it to, onclick="javascript:postBackByObject(event)"

```
                   <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">

                            function postBackByObject(mEvent) {
                                var o;
                                // Internet Explorer    
                                if (mEvent.srcElement) {
                                    o = mEvent.srcElement;
                                }
                                    // Netscape and Firefox
                                else if (mEvent.target) {
                                    o = mEvent.target;
                                }
                                if (o.tagName == "INPUT" && o.type == "checkbox") {
                                    __doPostBack("", "");
                                }
                            }
                        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your asp element is missing autopostback property

> <asp:TreeView ID="tv_WLG" runat="server" OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="tv_WLG_TreeNodeCheckChanged"   ShowCheckBoxes="All">
> AutoPostBack="true"</asp:TreeView>

Without it it won't trigger